# Is there a Libadalang enumeration or type that corresponds to ASIS's Flat_Element_Kind?

Tags: ada

I am currently trying to convert a program that previously used AdaCore's ASIS library to be compatible with Libadalang instead. Does anyone know of a direct translation for the Element_Flat_Kinds type and corresponding functions or know of resources for converting between the two?